# MySQL return sum of sales by days for a week with keeping empty values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to return a sum of transactions amount for each day separately for a week, I done that using this query:

```
SELECT DATE(`TransactionTime`) as days, SUM(`TransactionAmount`) AS SalesRevenue
FROM sales
WHERE TransactionTime BETWEEN '2021-03-21' AND '2021-03-27' GROUP BY
DATE(TransactionTime)
```

but it is not return all days because there is some days are not exists. so I need this days to be there with zero value for sales like this:

[image]

**instead of this:**

[image]

Note: the top above table is made by page inspector

Comment: You should add calendar table and fetch days from that table maybe.

Comment: But consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: The data is for a js chart, and every thing is handled in array for the chart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "keeping" values, because they are not in the table.  You need to generate them.  This is simple enough with a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive dates as (
    select date('2021-03-21') as dte
    union all
    select dte + interval 1 day
    from dates
    where dte < '2021-03-27' 
    )
select d.dte, coalesce(sum(TransactionAmount), 0) as SalesRevenue
from dates d left join
     sales s 
     on s.TransactionTime >= d.dte and
        s.TransactionTime < d.dte + interval 1 day
group by d.dte
```

Comment: Perfect solution, but I add a last touch at the end ( ORDER BY dte ASC), Thanks a lot dear.